# Как сохранить содержимое файла в YAML-структуре

Tags: ansible

Есть переменная content, которую я получил посредством {{ lookup('template', 'config1.yml.j2') }} и в которой содержится содержимое одного конфигурационного файла.

Необходимо, в другом jinja-темплейте вытащить содержимое переменной content и поместить в другой файл, который имеет структуру yaml-файла вида:

```
config_file:
- name: 'file-name'
  mode: '0600'
  path: '/tmp/file-name'
  content: |
    < line1 >
    < line2 >
    < lineN >
```

Строки Line - это конфигурационный файл из переменной content, располагающийся с отступом относительно начала строки, чего я добиться не могу.

Может есть другие варианты?

Основная задача получить готовый файл из первого темплейта и сохранить его содержимое в другом файле внутри yaml-структура в виде, который описан выше.